# Flash game data storage

Tags: database, flash

I'm storing a variety of variables containing statistics, items weapons, etc in a flash based game.  Currently I'm using PHP and AMFPHP as a backend, calling services to pull the data.  This is fine for my own machine, even my own website, however if I want to deploy the game to a site such as Kongregate or ArmorGames, what storage method can I use at that point?

I have a small preference of continuing to use a database such as MySQL because I spent some time designing the ER diagram and schema, but if I have to store in a flat file, I can do that too.  I'm especially interested in others who have deployed games which have data storage (such as inventory, characters, classes, items, mobs) external to their game.

Edit: Looking for answers as to whether people use remote services or another solution for deploying their games to sites such as this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked within Kongregate's developers, the answer is yes, I can use remote web services.  The API unfortunately had nothing in it dealing with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should peruse the documentation of the respective providers:

http://www.kongregate.com/developer_center/docs/shared-content-api

Not sure if armor games has any of that type.

Comment: Thanks, I poked around a bit in that section already but it didn't address saving large amounts of data on a database type structure.  That was more for doing simple SharedObjects between users so they could use each others levels.  Also, the shared content API states you can only save 10 types of data, and I have almost 10 objects alone, not counting the properties.  That would be more parsing than I would prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use our backend Flox http://gamua.com/flox/. It allows you to store your inventories, characters, etc. It's not MySQL but based on a NoSQL database. However, since you'd be using the AS3 SDK, you would not get in touch with the DB anyway.

Also, I should mention that I am the lead developer of Flox, which may make me a bit biased. ;-)